# No libOpenCL.so file found

Tags: python, c++, amazon-ec2, cmake, lightgbm

I'm trying to install LightGBM with gpu version on AWS EC2 Instance, linux 20.04 image. Firstly I have installed cuda and nvidia as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Then, here's installation step for LightGBM:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
apt-get install -y -qq libboost-all-dev

cd LightGBM
rm -r build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include/ ..
```

Everything is working fine till here, now `make` is giving me a problem:

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

Error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so', needed by '../lightgbm'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so', needed by '../lib_lightgbm.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Am I installing something in wrong directory or something? I have installed `cuda and nvidia-graphic` in root directory.

Instance info:

```
Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM), p3.2Xlarge
```

So my Cuda was installed in different directory so I did this step again with correct directory:

```
cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/cuda/include/ ..
```

Then:

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

Output:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/boosting.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/application/application.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt_model_text.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/boosting.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt_prediction.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/prediction_early_stop.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/bin.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/config.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/config_auto.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt_model_text.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/dataset.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/dataset_loader.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/gbdt_prediction.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/file_io.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/boosting/prediction_early_stop.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/bin.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/json11.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/metadata.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/config.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/config_auto.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/parser.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/train_share_states.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/io/tree.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/dataset.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/metric/dcg_calculator.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/metric/metric.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/network/ifaddrs_patch.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/network/linker_topo.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/dataset_loader.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/network/linkers_mpi.cpp.o
[ 49%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/network/linkers_socket.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/network/network.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/objective/objective_function.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/cuda_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/file_io.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/json11.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/metadata.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:9:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/linear_tree_learner.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:8:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/parser.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/train_share_states.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.cpp:7:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
[ 68%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/io/tree.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/metric/dcg_calculator.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/metric/metric.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/network/ifaddrs_patch.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/network/linker_topo.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/network/linkers_mpi.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/network/linkers_socket.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/tree_learner.cpp:8:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:11:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/network/network.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so', needed by '../lib_lightgbm.so'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/src/c_api.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/objective/objective_function.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/cuda_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/linear_tree_learner.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:9:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:8:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.cpp:7:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/tree_learner.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so', needed by '../lightgbm'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/src/treelearner/voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/tree_learner.cpp:8:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/CL/cl.h:32,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/cl.hpp:19,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/config.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/buffer.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/external_libs/compute/include/boost/compute/core.hpp:18,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/gpu_tree_learner.h:33,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/parallel_tree_learner.h:16,
                 from /home/ubuntu/LightGBM/src/treelearner/voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp:11:
/usr/include/CL/cl_version.h:34:104: note: #pragma message: cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)
   34 | #pragma message("cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 220 (OpenCL 2.2)")
      |                                                                                                        ^
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/_lightgbm.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/lightgbm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I installed `libOpenCL.so` and the copied it from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so` to `/usr/lib/cuda/lib64/` . Will it be same file which I need or will it be different?

Comment: Do you **actually** have a file `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so` which you specified as a value for variable `OpenCL_LIBRARY`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev hey thanks for pointing that out, my cuda was installed in ```/usr/lib/``` but I cannot find file ```libOpenCL.so``` inside, have I missed something while installing cuda or something?

Comment: Do not copy library. Just set variable `OpenCL_LIBRARY` to point on the library's **actual** location.